# How to search a string in a file

Tags: python, regex

I have to search `s="xyz-123."` s in a file . `s` is coming from some other code

```
import re
s="xyz-123."  # This will come from some other code

f=open("\path","r")
searched_item = re.findall(r's[-]+?[0-9a-zA-Z-]+[-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+[.]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+[.]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+', f.read())
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I have to search s="xyz-123." s in a file . s is coming from some other code

Comment: file contents as  sosreport-vlmanutslab1.123-20160229014706-74c1.tar.xz

sosreport-vlmanutslab1.123-20160229014706-74c1.tar.xz.md5

sosreport-vlmanutslab1-20160227083027-4abd.tar.xz

sosreport-vlmanutslab1-20160227083027-4abd.tar.xz.md5

sosreport-vlmanutslab1-20160229024320-3738.tar.xz

sosreport-vlmanutslab1-20160229024320-3738.tar.xz.md5

sosreport-vlmanutslab1.3-12156812661-20160227081447-dbea.tar.xz

sosreport-vlmanutslab1.3-12156812661-20160227081447-dbea.tar.xz.md5

Comment: read each line from file `s` and perform the `regex` operation

Comment: s is the string which i have to search . Please see the code.

Answer (score 1):

If `s` is a fixed string then it would be simpler to use `find` in string rather than involving `regex`

```
def findall(p, s):
    '''Yields all the positions of
    the pattern p in the string s.'''
    i = s.find(p)
    while i != -1:
        yield i
        i = s.find(p, i+1)

import re
s="xyz-123."  # This will come from some other code
f=open("\path","r")
file_content = f.read()
for match_index in findall(s, file_content):
    print match_index
```